# Array of objects to accumulate all object properties for which another property is the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

Let's say my array of objects looks like:

```
array1 = [
    { 
         rule: {
             column: "colName",
             value: "val1"
         }
    },
    { 
         rule: {
             column: "colName",
             value: "val2"
         }
    },
    { 
         rule: {
             column: "colName",
             value: "val3"
         }
    },
    { 
         rule: {
             column: "colName2",
             value: "val4"
         }
    }
]
```

I want to write something like a `reduce` operation that checks if `rule.column` are equal for all array elements and if so, to push into the values of one of them while removing the others.
To give me something like:

```
array2 = [
    { 
         rule: {
             column: "colName",
             value: ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
         }
    },
    { 
         rule: {
             column: "colName2",
             value: ["val4"]
         }
    }
]
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this?
I can definitely write a regular `function` to do this, but I am assuming I should be able to do a `reduce` operation on `array1` instead?

**Edit**: the original question had `otherProperty: {}` properties after `rule` but my object doesn't actually have that (it's on the upper-level object)

Comment: What have you tried? You might start by creating an index to the first instance of values, then when you find a duplicate, you can push the value to the right spot then *splice* the current element. *reduceRight* is very handy for just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just create an object with keys matching each column, push to the internal `values` array, and then grab the object's values:

```js
const input = [{
    rule: {
      column: "colName",
      value: 'v1'
    },
    otherProperty: 'otherProp',
  },
  {
    rule: {
      column: "colName",
      value: 'v2'
    },
    otherProperty: 'otherProp',
  },
  {
    rule: {
      column: "colName",
      value: 'val3',
    },
    otherProperty: 'otherProp',
  },
  {
    rule: {
      column: "colName2",
      value: 'val4'
    },
    otherProperty: 'otherProp',
  }
];
const outputCols = input.reduce((outputCols, { rule: { column, value }, ...otherProps}) => {
  if (!outputCols[column]) {
    outputCols[column] = { rule: { column, value: [] }, ...otherProps };
  }
  outputCols[column].rule.value.push(value);
  return outputCols;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(outputCols));
```

Note that if the `otherProps` are different in subsequent objects, they'll be ignored currently.

Comment: Oh, wow, this is great! I actually just realized that `otherProperty` is outside the array so it's definitely not a problem.

Comment: You need to be a little careful with `!outputCols[column]` as the value of *column* may match the name of an own or inherited property of *outputCols*, or if `outputCols[column]` returns a falsey value (e.g. `0` or ""). A more robust test is `!outputCols.hasOwnProperty(column)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG `outputCols` is the accumulator that is initialized to `{}`, so that shouldn't be an issue unless the column name is something ridiculous like `__proto__` or `hasOwnProperty`, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance—you could use `Object.create(null)` for the accumulator, but it doesn't fix the falsey value issue. Not really an issue in this case, but when applied more generally it may be. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `reduce` to group and then get the values as an array.

The name `otherProperty` is out of scope, but you can use either the function `Object.assign` or the Spread syntax.

```js
let array1 = [    {          rule: {             column: "colName",             value: ["val1"]         },         otherProperty: {}    },    {          rule: {             column: "colName",             value: ["val2"]         },         otherProperty: {}    },    {          rule: {             column: "colName",             value: ["val3"]         },         otherProperty: {}    },    {          rule: {             column: "colName2",             value: ["val4"]         },         otherProperty: {}    }],
    result = Object.values(array1.reduce((a, c) => {
      (a[c.rule.column] || (a[c.rule.column] = {rule: {column: c.rule.column, value: []}, otherProperty: {}})).rule.value.push(...c.rule.value);
      return a;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```